# Error work with proxy. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: node.js, proxy

I make requests to instagram through a proxy.  This error occurs regularly.  Where does the problem occur?  Am I using bad, unstable proxies?  Or is it struggling with Instagram itself?  A month or two ago, this problem did not arise.

```
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 instead of IPv6 helped me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).